# Cannot invoke != with an argument list of type SKNode?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm following a tutorial on an intro to SpriteKit, and I'm getting this error, in the tutorial, it is just like this, but the tutorial was posted a few months back, so some of the syntax might have changed.

The error comes up in the **if helloNode != nil { ... }**

Any help?

Thanks!

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var helloNode:SKNode = childNodeWithName("helloNode")!

//I get the error in the next line
    if helloNode != nil {
        helloNode.name = nil

        var moveUp:SKAction = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 100, duration: 0.5)
        var zoom:SKAction = SKAction.scaleTo(2, duration: 0.25)
        var pause:SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
        var fadeAway = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.25)
        var remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
        var moveSequence = SKAction.sequence([moveUp, zoom, pause, fadeAway, remove])
        helloNode.runAction(moveSequence)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
var helloNode:SKNode = childNodeWithName("helloNode")!
```

the return value of `childNodeWithName`, which is an optional, is applied the forced unwrapping operator, which:

- throws a runtime exception if the return value is nil
- evaluates to a non optional `SKNode` if the return value is not nil

Besides that, `helloNode` is declared as a non optional `SKNode`, and a non optional can never be nil.

To fix the compilation error, do the following changes:

```
var helloNode: SKNode? = childNodeWithName("helloNode")

if let helloNode = helloNode {
    ...
}
```

With these changes, `helloNode` is an optional `SKNode`, which can contain either nil or an instance of `SKNode`. In the next like optional binding is used: if `helloNode` is nil, the `let helloNode = helloNode` evaluates to false, and the code in the `if` statement is skipped. On the other hand, if `helloNode` is not nil, the value it contains is unwrapped and assigned to a non optional variable (having the same name, but you can choose any name you want) whose scope is limited to the code block of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

The `!` at the end of `childNodeWithName("helloNode")!` means that the value cannot be nil, so the nil check is invalid. Try this:

```
 if let temp = helloNode {
    // use temp instead of helloNode

    ...
}
```

Or change your variable declaration line to this:

```
var helloNode:SKNode? = childNodeWithName("helloNode")
```

You can read more about how to work with Optionals here: [Optionals in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_496)

Answer (score 0):

There are decent answers here already, but they (and the original question) involve code that isn't as concise or clear as it might be.

1. The return type of `childNodeWithName` is already optional (`SKNode?`), so there's no need to explicitly declare it when assigning to your local `helloNode` variable. Likewise, type inference lets you not need to declare the types for all the `SKAction`s you're creating.
2. Using `if let` and shadowing the locally bound non-optional with the same name as the enclosing scope's optional is not the most readable of code.
3. Besides, if you're only assigning to `helloNode` once and only using it after checking that assignment, you only need it bound in one scope. And speaking of only assigning to a name once, there's no need to use `var` for things that won't change.
4. `SKAction`s are reusable. If this is going to happen more than once in the course of your game, you might consider creating `moveSequence` once (lazily even) and stashing it in a property.

So, an improved version:

```
lazy var moveSequence: SKAction = {
    let moveUp = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 100, duration: 0.5)
    let zoom = SKAction.scaleTo(2, duration: 0.25)
    let pause = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
    let fadeAway = SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(0.25)
    let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    return SKAction.sequence([moveUp, zoom, pause, fadeAway, remove])
}()

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let helloNode == childNodeWithName("helloNode") {
        helloNode.name = nil
        helloNode.runAction(moveSequence)
    }
}
```